# Can a cube be retracted to its boundary?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

> **Definition**: If $A$ is a subspace of topological space $X$, then a continuous function $r:X\rightarrow A$ such that $r(x)=x$, for each
> $x\in A$ is called a retraction of $X$ onto $A$.

My professor said that there is no retraction of the cube $Q^{n+1}=\{t\in R^{n+1}:||t_i||\leq 1 ,i=1,...,n+1\}$ has no retraction to it is boundary $S^n$. Hewever, there is a retraction from $Q^{n+1}|\{0\}$ to $S^n$. Why is this true? Could someone please help me to understand this?

Comment: If there was a retraction then $Q^{n+1}$ and $S^n$ would be homotopy equivalent. This is impossible, just have a look at the homology groups.
If you remove the origin from the $(n+1)$-cube you can use a radial projection to construct the retraction.

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain, does the point that we remove have to be the origin or could it be any point in the cube?

Comment: @gbd Any point not on the boundary will do. You can use the same technique too: Draw a straight line from the missing interior point to the boundary, and project the whole line onto that boundary point.

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain only deformation retractions are homotopy equivalences, every (nonempty) space retracts to any of its points through the constant map

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I think that was what the OP was referring to otherwise, as you observed the professor claim would be false and the statement trivial.
Thank you for clearing it out nonetheless.

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain that's not what I meant. Not only there is no deformation retraction from the cube to its boundary since they are not homotopy equivalent, but there is no retraction either, which is sometimes called the "no retraction theorem" (a retraction has to be the identity on the subspace one retracts to, so a constant map won't work here)

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Ah! Now I see what you mean, I think I underestimated the question, I should have looked at it more carefully. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the max norm

$$\lVert (x_1,\ldots,x_n)\rVert_m=\max\{|x_1|,\ldots,|x_n|\}$$

Then your $Q^n$ is nothing else than the unital ball in the max norm:

$$Q^n=\{v\in\mathbb{R}^n\ |\ \lVert v\rVert_m\leq 1\}$$

So lets forget for a moment about this concrete norm and consider any normed space $(V,\lVert\cdot\rVert)$. Then consider the unital ball and the unital sphere:

$$B=\{v\in V\ |\ \lVert v\rVert\leq 1\}$$
$$S=\{v\in V\ |\ \lVert v\rVert= 1\}$$

With that setup we have the famous:

> **Theorem.** The following statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. $S$ is not a retract of $B$
> 2. Any continuous map $f:B\to B$ has a fixed point ([Brouwer fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem))
> 3. $S$ is not contractible
> 4. $V$ is finite dimensional

which is a nontrivial result. You can google it, there are many sites which will cover the proof (including wikipedia I believe).

On the other hand we have:

> **Lemma.** $S$ is a retract of $B\backslash\{0\}$ (regardless of what $V$ is).

*Proof.* Take

$$r:B\backslash\{0\}\to S$$
$$r(v)=\frac{1}{\lVert v\rVert}\cdot v$$

It is well defined because $v\neq 0$. I leave as an exercise that it is a continuous retraction. $\Box$

Finally note that for any $v\in int(B)$ there is a homeomorphism $f:B\backslash\{v\}\to B\backslash\{0\}$ such that $f(x)=x$ for $x\in S$. Therefore we can replace $0$ with any other interior point.